# Symfony app and API on same Apache virtual host

Tags: php, apache, symfony, virtualhost, kerberos

I work on a legacy PHP application powered by Symfony v3 on Apache 2.4. This app is secured by a Kerberos authentication. My Apache VirtualHost looks like :

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/app"

    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "App Login"
    KrbMethodNegotiate On
    KrbMethodK5Passwd On
    KrbAuthRealms MY_REALM 
    KrbLocalUserMapping On
    Krb5KeyTab /usr/local/apache2/keytab/apache.keytab
    require valid-user

    # Symfony URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

    [...]
```

I added an API to this app, with URL looking like `/api/users`. The problem is that, like my whole application, this API is secured by Kerberos, but I don't want to. So I tried to add a LocationMatch tag to my vhost that way :

```
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/app"

    <LocationMatch "^((?!/api).)*$">
        AuthType Kerberos
        AuthName "App Login"
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd On
        KrbAuthRealms MY_REALM 
        KrbLocalUserMapping On
        Krb5KeyTab /usr/local/apache2/keytab/apache.keytab
        require valid-user
    </LocationMatch>

    [...]
```

This could have worked but there's a problem. It seems that URL rewriting is executed BEFORE and my URI is transformed this form :
    /api/users => /app.php/api/users

And I don't manage to apply my LocationMatch on this new URI.

I'm blocked. How can I access my legacy application secured by Kerberos, and publish my API without authentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it.

First problem, the use of **mod_rewrite** to redirect to the front controller is in the Directory directive. Directory directives are processed before Location directives, so my URL is rewrited before my Location directive. So my API url become `/app.php/api`, and the part after the script name can't be filtered with a Location directive. As mentioned in the Symfony Book, I replaced url rewriting by the Apache command FallbackResource which do the same thing (reroute to my Symfony front controller), but it's possible to filter on my `/api` URL with a Location directive... so it should have been possible to use `<LocationMatch "^((?!/api).)*$">`.

But the second problem I faced is that LocationMatch (or `Location ~` which seems to do the same thing) work on a "positive lookahead" like `^/api` but it seems there's a bug in Apache 2.4.10 (maybe due to Kerberos module) when I use "negative lookahead" like `/(?!api)`. The LocationMatch directive content is processed even for `/api` URL...

I finally tried another solution, which work in my case and solve the problem :

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/app"

<Directory /var/www/app>
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "App Login"
    KrbMethodNegotiate On
    KrbMethodK5Passwd On
    KrbAuthRealms MY_REALM 
    KrbLocalUserMapping On
    Krb5KeyTab /usr/local/apache2/keytab/apache.keytab
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/api noauth=1
    <RequireAny>
        Require env noauth
        Require valid-user
    </RequireAny>

    FallbackResource /app.php
</Directory>
```